# How to use class from DLL referenced by referenced DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have 3 C# projects: P1, P2 and P3. I have class A in project P1 that I compile as assembly and get DLL. I reference project P1 in project P2 and use class A, and also compile it as assembly and get DLL. In addition, I reference project P2 in project P3 and want to use class A (from project P1) as well, but unfortunately, class A is not available. The reference sequence is as follows:

P1 -> P2 -> P3

I am using Visual Studio 2019 for development.

Please advise how to make class A from project P1 be visible in project P3.

Thank you

Comment: Add a reference to P1

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested, the direct way is to add the reference P1 to P3.

Also, if you don't want to add the reference P1, you can create a new class to inherit from the classA in the P2.

Like the following:

```
public class ExampleB:ExampleA
    {
        ....
    }
```